# What is the use of global pointer in a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, global-variables

I have started learning linked lists recently and while learning how to write code for displaying the linked list i came across this so called global pointer in a structure.So can you please tell me why it was used and what it does.

```
struct Node{
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
 }*first=NULL;
//i am asking about the above pointer *first=NULL
```

Comment: It will depend on the context.

Comment: `first` is not in the structure. It's a global pointer that can point to an element of that structure. It's used to point to the beginning of the linked list.

Comment: `first` is not in the structure. `first` is a variable of type `struct Node *` that is being initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: The code is a combination of the definition of a structure `struct Node` and a pointer to such a structure named `first` which is initialized as `NULL` meaning it points to nothing. Based on the name `first`, this might be a pointer to the first element of a linked list which empty at this point. (But without seeing more code this is just a guess, and it is unclear if it is necessary to have the pointer as a global variable or if it should better be `static`.)

Answer (score 0):

A global pointer like this is often tied to a specific resource that the developer had only wanted accessed through the module's header file. Such as a system-wide storage of valid devices or buffer locations. If this code slice is initialized at global scope, it starts with no data, and other functions can add or remove data from it. Others can see the whole list of data by receiving the pointer `first` from some function (or extern) and iterating through the pointer references in `next` until NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`first` isn't part of the structure - it's a variable of type "pointer to `struct Node`".  It's most likely intended to point to the first element of the list.  Normally you wouldn't have the head of the list be a global variable - you'd create it in `main` (or whatever main driver) and pass it as an argument to the various routines that manipulate the list:

```
struct Node { ... };

int main( void )
{
  struct Node *first = calloc( 1, sizeof *first );
  ...
  /**
   * The following is a stand-in for however you get the values
   * to add to the list
   */
  int x;
  while( get_next_value( &x ) )
    insert( first, x );

  display( first );
  ...
}
```